# drush xmlsitemap-regenerate domain is incorrect

Tags: 7, drush

Whenever I run:

```
drush xmlsitemap-regenerate
```

on our live server, the domains in the sitemap all refer to:

```
http://default
```

Only when I generate the sitemap from the Drupal admin backend, do I get the correct sitemap.xml with the correct domain setup.

I need to have the drush command working correctly, as we're using it with a Capistrano deploy script.

Can I somehow pass the domain name to the drush command?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your default base URL under the 'Advanced' fieldset. in `admin/config/search/xmlsitemap` (D7 version) ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `--uri` to your command.

Example:

```
drush --uri=example.com xmlsitemap-regenerate
```